# Condition expression for attribute of list element in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to make a condition expression for a list append operation so it won't perform the append if there is already an item in the list containing a matching `id` attribute. For example, suppose I have a list that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    id: "id-one",
    size: 4,
    color: "blue" 
  },
  {
    id: "id-two",
    size: 7,
    color: "blue"
  },
  {
    id: "id-three",
    size: 2,
    color: "red"
  }
]
```

My update expression is:

`SET #list_attribute_name = list_append(if_not_exists(#list_attribute_name, []), :more_items)`

But I can't figure out how to generate a condition expression that checks the ID of the elements in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this, not unless you know the position of the item in the list. You have two options:

1. Read the item first (which could cause race conditions at scale)
2. Change your list to a map

```
{
    "id-one": {
        "id": "id-one",
        "size": 4,
        "color": "blue"
    },
    "id-two": {
        "id": "id-two",
        "size": 7,
        "color": "blue"
    },
    "id-three": {
        "id": "id-three",
        "size": 2,
        "color": "red"
    }
}
```

`UpdateExpression='SET #map_attribute_name.#id = :more_items'`
`ConditionExpression='attribute_not_exists(#map_attribute_name.#id)`